# What is $\mathbb{E}[W(\tau)^4]$ for a Wiener process $W$ and a stopping time $\tau$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I know that $\mathbb{E}[W(t)^2] = t$ and $\mathbb{E}[W(t)^4] = 3t^2$ for a standard Wiener process $W(t)$ when $t$ is a (non-stochastic) number.  I also know that $\mathbb{E}[W(\tau)^2] = \mathbb{E}[\tau]$ for a stopping time $\tau$.  The question is: can $\mathbb{E}[W(\tau)^4]$ be expressed in terms of $\mathbb{E}[\tau^n]$, too?

I would also appreciate if an accessible reference is introduced (at the level of Evans's "Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations").  Also if there is a general result for higher moments of $W(\tau)$ that would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process $W(t)^4-6tW(t)^2+3t^2$ is a martingale. So if $\tau$ is a reasonable stopping time (e.g., bounded) then $\Bbb E[W(\tau)^4] =6\Bbb E[\tau W(\tau)^2]-3\Bbb E[\tau^2]$. To go further you need to know something about the joint distribution of $\tau$ and $W(\tau)^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly, I am not familiar with martingales. But I could find the same result by applying $\mathbb{E}[(\int_0^\tau FdW)^2] = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^\tau F^2 dt]$ to $F=W$.

Comment: I have $dX = a e^{-3t} dt + b dW$ for positive $a$ and $b$. And $\tau$ is the first time $X$ reaches a particular $x_f$, given that it starts from $X=0$ at $t=0$. Any idea how that helps finding $\mathbb{E}[\tau W^2]$?

Comment: I figured out how to compute $\mathbb{E}[\tau W^2]$ in my case of interest. It's actually trivial, but just for the reference here it goes: Since $x_f = a(1-e^{-\tau})/3 + bW(\tau)$, I can just solve for $W(\tau)$ and insert in $\mathbb{E}[\tau W^2]$ so that everything is in terms of $\tau$.